# how to retrieve meta data from a multipart/form-data Audio file upload to api asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, api

I'm not really even sure where to start on this I can't seem to find much online.  How to get the metadata of a song such as Artist, Album etc from the stream that I get when I submit the file as a multipart/form-data to my Web API controller.

I'm saving the files in Azure blob storage but in my DB I want to store all the metadata. When I download the file from the blob to my desktop the metadata is attached to the new file so that leads me to believe I can get it out of the stream somehow but I can't find anything on this.

I've just been reading docs and not finding what I'm looking for if you have any suggested reading that would be helpful

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript library? Here's a good one that might help you out https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you save the file to disk. You can use

https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

To read the id3 meta data of the song. I saw some examples, you may be able to read direct from the stream as you save the file even.